# Invalid or corrupt jarfile myjavafile.jar Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar

Currently I have `myjavafile.jar` on local pc with `windows` os

I tried to upload the file on my ubuntu server using `WinScp`

The transferring of the file was success

But the problem is when I try to run the file using this command

`java -jar myjavafile.jar`

The ubuntu terminal shows this error

`Invalid or corrupt jarfile myjavafile.jar`

How come the file is invalid or corrupted? Where the file is running fine on my local.

After copying the jar file using WinSCP the file name suddenly turns to red font-color seems like it's corrupted. But the file isn't corrupted in my local.

[image]

Comment: Does `java -jar myjavafile.jar` work fine on Windows?

Comment: yes sir it works fine on windows

Comment: Try to run it with: `java -cp myjavafile.jar your.package.Application`. If it works then the issue in your manifest file.

Comment: Are the file sizes the same?

Comment: I downloaded the file with 34mb but in my downloads folder says it's 1kb?

Comment: Did you try any other software to copy the .jar file?

Comment: Can you post a session log file of WinsCP showing the file upload and subsequent listing of the remote directory?

Comment: Red color in ls (on Ubuntu) has nothing to do with any corruption, it's done for [any archive file, including jar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls). Are you using FTP protocol in WinSCP and if so what Transfer Mode?